# Declare Lambda Expression as a class constant field

Tags: c#, class, lambda, expression, field

Why isn't it possible to declare a class constant filed of type `Lambda Expression`. I want Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public const Expression<Func<string,bool>> MyExpr = (string s) => s=="Hello!";
}
```

But I get the compile error: `Expression cannot contain anonymous methods or lambda expressions`

Comment: Are you sure we see your exact code? Do you use `s` in another sense elsewhere?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes I'm sure. *s* is not used anywhere else. Don't you have this problem? Can you declare such a field?

Comment: @Alireza: Yes you can. I just copy/pasted the code and it worked just fine. EDIT: Unless, did you mean you wanted `public LambdaExpression...` instead of `public Expression<...`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Careless me! I have problem when it is going to be declared as *const*. Updated the question. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Based on your update, you can't use `const`, you'd have to use `readonly`. `const` requires that it be a compile-time constant; something you could imagine being copy/pasted wherever you use `MyExpr`. `readonly` will be resolved at runtime as though you just were referencing a field.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You are right. I lost the main point of the *constant*s. Thanks so much.

Comment: The only `const` value of type `Expression<Func<string, bool>>` you can have, is `null`. But the error message was confusing. I have not tried to compile the above code myself (yet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a limitation of C# and CLR.  Only primitive numeric values, string literals and `null` can be used as a value of a constant field.  Expression trees are represented as a normal graph of objects and can't appear as a constant value.

Answer (score 4):

Reproduced. That is a strange error message from the compiler. I would expect instead:

> error CS0134: '(field)' is of type '(type)'. A const field of a reference type
>   other than string can only be initialized with null.

The message we do get is misleading. *Some* C# expressions (I am not talking about .NET expression trees `Expression<...>`) can clearly contain a lambda expression, but they don't say *why* this particular expression cannot.

The solution is to make a `static readonly` field instead:

```
class MyClass
{
   public static readonly Expression<Func<string, bool>> MyExpr
     = s => s == "Hello!";
}
```

Only one instance of `Expression<>` will ever be created, but it is no compile-time constant, there is actually some code that will run once (just) before `MyClass` is used for the first time.

Comment: *Some C# expressions (I am not talking about .NET expression trees Expression<...>) can clearly contain a lambda expression* would you please make an example?

Comment: @Alireza The expression `filtered = myList.Where(x => x.Status.IsValid)` does contain a lambda expression.